# Responsive box grid with bootstrap-4 different box heights

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I tried to make a responsive grid of 6 textboxes with the box class and bootstrap.

My problem is , that with different amount of text in it the box they have different widths / heights, but i want them to have the same max-height / max-width as the box with the most text in it.

Is there a chance to get this done without hard-coding the width / height for all boxes?

Here's a code snippet:

```css
/***** Box *****/

.flex-box {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: ;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 40px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background-color: rgb(170, 230, 255);
}

.flex-box:hover {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<!-- Textbox-Sections -->
<section id="about_me" class="section-padding title">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container pt-4">
      <h1 class="title">About me</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="flex-box">
            <h1 class="boxtitle">My way</h1>
            <p class="lead">
              <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti fuga iusto aspernatur magni rem quas deserunt repellendus hic fugit amet tempora labore perferendis, voluptate possimus itaque cum molestias dolores. Omnis?</div>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="flex-box">
            <h1 class="boxtitle">My way</h1>
            <p class="lead">
              <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse voluptatum soluta cum provident explicabo fugiat dolores odit blanditiis dolorem magni. Quaerat temporibus doloremque beatae voluptatum dignissimos? Eligendi voluptatum similique
                incidunt!
              </div>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="flex-box">
            <h1 class="boxtitle">My way</h1>
            <p class="lead">
              <div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate ipsam neque recusandae similique. Inventore repellendus aliquid delectus explicabo dolore sapiente voluptas nihil dolorem tempore voluptates, nemo ipsum cumque animi quidem.</div>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="flex-box">
            <h1 class="boxtitle">My way</h1>
            <p class="lead">
              <div>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod illo incidunt nihil praesentium minus itaque hic, soluta dicta cupiditate quos dolorum esse, harum placeat, qui veritatis animi sunt? Ab, nobis.</div>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="flex-box">
            <h1 class="boxtitle">My way</h1>
            <p class="lead">
              <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, fuga vel. Maxime hic tempore quo animi ex vero doloribus dolores quos, sapiente delectus dolor et laborum amet quam aspernatur earum.</div>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="flex-box">
            <h1 class="boxtitle">My way</h1>
            <p class="lead">
              <div>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta, repellendus distinctio ratione autem consequatur rerum libero nesciunt ullam eaque molestias odit architecto nisi incidunt quasi omnis ut. Natus, exercitationem alias.</div>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Here's a link to the CodePen site](https://codepen.io/g-hammer/pen/NyvXBO?editors=1000)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the `.flex-box` height:100% so that it fills the `col-*`...

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GQORQV?editors=1100

```
.flex-box {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom:;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background-color: rgb(170, 230, 255);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response! That definitely solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

As @Abhijeet stated it is only possible to use css if the boxes are horizontally aligned. Otherwise you can use this jQuery snippet:

```
var max_height = 0;
var max_width = 0;
$('.equal-size').each(function(e) {
  h = $(this).height();
  if(typeof(h) != "undefined") {
   if(h > max_height) {
     max_height = h;
   }
  }
  w = $(this).width();
  if(typeof(w) != "undefined") {
   if(w > max_width) {
     max_width = w;
   }
  }
});
if(max_height > 0) {
  $('.equal-size').height(max_height);
}
if(max_width > 0) {
  $('.equal-size').width(max_width);
}
```

You need to give the elements the class  `equal-size`.

It is looking for the max height/width and applying it to every element.

---

This is only working if you have only one group of elements that should have same height/width. If you have more you need to give the group numbers and change the classes appropriately  (`equal-size-1`, `equal-size-2`, ...) and use this snippet:

```
var numberOfGroups = 2;
for(var i=1; i<numberOfGroups+1; i++) {
    var max_height = 0;
    var max_width = 0;
    $('.equal-size-'+String(i)).each(function(e) {
      h = $(this).height();
      if(typeof(h) != "undefined") {
       if(h > max_height) {
         max_height = h;
       }
      }
      w = $(this).width();
      if(typeof(w) != "undefined") {
       if(w > max_width) {
         max_width = w;
       }
      }
    });
    if(max_height > 0) {
      $('.equal-size-'+String(i)).height(max_height);
    }
    if(max_width > 0) {
      $('.equal-size-'+String(i)).width(max_width);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible with only with css but yes if you are making these boxes vertical I mean one to each other then definitely its possible but not horizontally. Same height possible in the grid if section are align one to each other like --[image]